# retrieve items of a parent without nested loops

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to have a collection with all books. Books belong to a bookstore and on the bookstore, there is a global scope.

When I do: bookstores = BookStore::all() and pass this to a view, I can do:
pseudocode:

```
for each $bookstores as $bookstore
   for each $bookstore->books as $book
   end
end
```

How can I sort all my books by name for example (and not first by bookstore and then by book like in the example)

I can not use $books = Books::all(), because the scope is on Bookstore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort them while fetching:

```
BookStore::with(['books' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('name');
}])-get();
```

To answer your other question from the comment below about getting all the books. You'd run something like this:

```
$collection->pluck('books')->collapse()->sortBy('name')
```

`pluck('books')` basically grabs all the books from the bookStores. This will give something like this:

```
[[book-a, book-c], [book-b]]
```

`collapse()` will merge all nested arrays changing the result to:

```
[book-a, book-c, book-b]
```

As you can see the sorting is off again, to fix this `sortBy('name')` will be called resulting in the following:

```
[book-a, book-b, book-c]
```

As you can see this is 'quite' a task which you might not want to do in your view. The way I would do this would be to create a [custom collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections#custom-collections) and add a method `books()` on there.

The method could look something like this:

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->pluck('books')->collapse()->sortBy('name');
}
```

Then you would have to make sure to overwrite the `newCollection` method in your `Book` model and return your custom collection. This would also end up in to the syntax you used in your example (in the comment below).

Comment: if I put $collection = BookStore::with(['books' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('name');
}])-get(); and pass the collection variable to my view, how do I get a list of all books? @foreach( $collection->books() as $book ) ?

Comment: I've updated the example. It was a bit too much to explain properly in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use Recursive function , you can get hierarchy with parent and child relation